# Segmentation Fault while malloc and sizeof

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Sorry if I'm offending anyone but I started learning C this week and I got a segmentation fault while compiling this. Can I please have a second pair of eyes to help me with this error?

```
void Space(void *empty, size_p s)
{
    empty = malloc(s);
}

int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    Space(p, sizeof(p));
    *p = 7;

    return;
}
```

Comment: What **is** `size-p`?

Answer (score 5):

`empty` is just a pointer variable - it contains "some" address, but it is still a local variable in the context of `Space`. If you want to update the value of `int *p` in `Space`, you'll need to pass a pointer to it:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    Space(&p, sizeof *p);
    *p = 7;

    return;
}

void Space(void **empty, size_p s)
{
    *empty = malloc(s);
}
```

Also, you have a bug where you call `Space`: `Space(p, sizeof(p));`

`sizeof(p)` is the size of the `int *` variable but you want to allocate the size of an `int` as that's what you're storing in `p`. So that line should instead be:
`Space(&p, sizeof *p);`

Answer (score 1):

```
void * Space(void *empty, size_t s)
{
    empty = malloc(s);
    return empty;
}

int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    p = Space(p, sizeof(int));
    *p = 7;

    return 0;
}
```

You can change the `Space` function to return a `void *` or an `int *`. The variable `empty` is a copy of the pointer in `main`. When you change the value in `Space`, because it is a copy, the change never makes it back to `main`.

I changed `sizeof(p)` to `sizeof(int)`. This is more of personal preference but I try to only give types as the argument to `sizeof`. You can get surprising results when you apply `sizeof` to variables.

I really like @DIMMSum's answer but I know pointer-to-a-pointer can be confusing especially when starting out.

Comment: Hm, your code is kind of odd - you take a parameter, set it, and then return it. Why not just return the call to malloc and get rid of the first parameter? But yeah this works too :-)

P.S. I personally don't think it's good to discourage people from applying sizeof to variables. The code is arguably more extensible because you can change the variable type and the sizeof calculation will still be correct.

Comment: @DIMMSum - I agree, normally I would just return from the call to `malloc`. I did it this way because I thought it was the easiest way to show the change in the code.